# converting Client type from Desktop to Web in Light Switch in Visual studio and running it. it shows a webpage to install silver light

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a problem with Light switch in visual studio. The application runs well in Desktop but when I change the client type to web and run it. It shows a web page to install Silver Light. I am unable to understand what exactly the problem is...

Comment: When you create a web client, you have the option of developing a Silverlight client or an HTML client. You, apparently, chose Sliverlight. So it needs Silverlight to run. Did you install Silverlight?

Comment: Yup i installed it. Anyways i reinstalled operating system and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are opening with Edge or Chrome browsers? Try it with Explorer 11